# What is the simplest way to convert vector to Toeplitz matrix in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to convert a vector to a symmetric Toeplitz matrix using Tensorflow operations like this:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[vector_size])
A = some_tensorflow_operation(a)
```

where the shape of A is [vector_size, vector_size]. The relation between the two variables is as below.

```
a = [a1,a2,a3]
A = [[a1,a2,a3],[a2,a1,a2],[a3,a2,a1]]
```

What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In case `vector_size=3`:

```
>>> a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[vector_size])
>>> A = [[a[0],a[1],a[2]],[a[1],a[0],a[1]],[a[2],a[1],a[0]]]
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> sess.run(A, {a: [1, 2, 3]})
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```